# How to monitor if my App is paused or resumed?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app where I want to track when the app is paused or resumed.

paused: User pressed the home button and the app is still running in the background.

resumed: app runs in background and user opens the app.

**How can I being notified when my app was paused/resumed?**

Comment: Please provide a technical definition for "paused" and "resumed" when it comes to an app.

Answer (score 1):

> paused: User pressed the home button and the app is still running in the background.

I am going to guess that the initial state is that one of your activities was in the foreground at the time the HOME button was pressed.

On the whole, there is no notion in Android of an "app" being in the foreground or the background, though we sometimes use that phrasing as shorthand for other scenarios.

Whatever activity was in the foreground will be called with `onPause()` and `onStop()` when the user presses HOME, but those events are also called in many other scenarios (e.g., user presses BACK). [`onUserLeaveHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29) will be called when the user presses HOME but not BACK, but `onUserLeaveHint()` is not called in other scenarios (e.g., incoming call screen takes over the foreground). Whether `onUserLeaveHint()` will meet your requirements, I cannot say.

> resumed: app runs in background and user opens the app.

`onStart()` and `onResume()`, at minimum, will be called on your activity that takes over the foreground. Those will be called at other times too, such as when the activity is coming onto the screen for the first time. There is also `onRestart()`, which will be called only if the activity is being started after having been stopped (i.e., after a prior `onStop()` call), which will weed out the newly-created-activity scenario. However, `onRestart()` will be called in other scenarios as well, such as part of a configuration change (e.g., screen rotation).

In general, what you are seeking is not really part of the Android architecture. You may need to approach your problem in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

In you Android activity you can override the [onPause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) and [onResume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) methods.

See the documentation on [Lifecycle Callbacks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks) for a list of other lifecycle callbacks that you can implement.